# I'd like to set a specific port number for visual studio 2017 API project

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2017

How can I set my API listen to port 1002?
In my vs2017 API project, I set the Project URL in the Project Properties to http://localhost:1002/
[image]
This works when debugging, but when I publish the project to a server, the port is no longer valid.

Comment: You need to set the port in IIS

Comment: This link help to you if you want change port on IIS:https://www.codeproject.com/articles/708718/how-to-change-default-port-of-iis-manager-from

Answer (score 2):

That port number `1002` is not common port.  If you are hosting the app in IIS, you will need to add the port number to the site in IIS.  You can have multiple site listening on different port in IIS.

[image: SonarQube]